# Convert a dateobject to list

Tags: list-manipulation, date-and-time

Im trying to extract a list of times from a list of Dates from the Sunrise function

```
Sunrises = 
  Sunrise[Entity["City", {"Lossiemouth", "Moray","UnitedKingdom"}], 
   DateRange[DateObject[{2019, 1, 1}], DateObject[{2019, 12, 31}]]]]
```

I have used this as a list of pairs and extracted the lastr elements so that the times are displayed using

```
Last /@ %2
```

Is it possible to convert this from the given format, to a list.
Such that the list only displays the the sunrise time for each day?

For example

Sunrise={0956,0956,0955} and so on.....

Thanks,

Luke

Comment: Using your `Last` approach: `DateValue[Last /@ Normal[Sunrises], {"Hour", "Minute"}]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sunrises = 
  Sunrise[Entity["City", {"Lossiemouth", "Moray","UnitedKingdom"}], 
   DateRange[DateObject[{2019, 1, 1}], DateObject[{2019, 1,5}]]]
```

You can use `DateString` on `Sunrises["Values"]` :

```
DateString[#, {"Hour", "Minute"}] & /@ Sunrises["Values"]
```

> {"0356", "0356", "0355", "0355", "0354"}

To get `{hour, minute}` pairs you can use `Part`:

```
Sunrises["Values"][[All, 1, 4 ;;]]
```

> {{3, 56}, {3, 56}, {3, 55}, {3, 55}, {3, 54}}

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @Luke4737, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept.